# ZF2 service locator interface does not return an object

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to create a model that will have access to the ZF2 service locator.

I have a model class that looks like this:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;


class testDelete implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
     protected $services;

   /**
   * construct function
   */
   public function  __construct ()
   {
     $router = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Router');
    }

  public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
  {
    $this->services = $serviceLocator;
  }

  public function getServiceLocator()
  {
    return $this->services;
  }
}
```

In reading the tutorials and blogs this should give me an instance of the service locator, which I can then use to call classes.  But when I call it I get a message

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object...

Does anyone know why this would be?

Do I need to some sort of setup to get the service locator interface to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your class implements `ServiceLocatorAware`, the service manager will automatically inject the service locator into it. However, it can only do that if the service manager is the thing instantiating the `testDelete` class. So you need to setup a service for `testDelete`.

Once you've done that, you still won't be able to call `$this->getServiceLocator()` from `__construct()`, as the dependency won't have been injected into the class yet.

If all you want is to get the router into your `testDelete` class, just create a service for `testDelete` and pass the router in as a dependency. This would be much easier than what you're currently trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set the "Router" service in the getServiceConfig() method of your Modules Module.php file:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return  array
            (
                'factories'     =>  array
                                    (
                                        'Router' => function($serviceManager)
                                                    {
                                                        ... your logic ...
                                                        return $Router
                                                    },
                                    ),

            );
}
```

Your Module.php file will look something like this:

```
namespace ModuleName;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;

/**
 * Tables (& Databases) Used in this Module
 */
use Your\Model\ModelName;
use Your\Mapper\ModelMapperName;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager           =   $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $serviceManager         =   $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $sharedManager          =   $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $moduleRouteListener    =   new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

        /**
         * Additional logic for Setting up Logging, Pre-Initializations, Exceptions etc
         */

    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return  array
                (
                    'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader'        =>  array
                                                                (
                                                                    include __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
                                                                ),
                    'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader'        =>  array
                                                                (
                                                                    'namespaces'    =>  array
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                                                                                        ),
                                                                ),
                );
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return  array
                (
                    'factories'     =>  array
                                        (
                                            'Router' => function($serviceManager)
                                                        {
                                                            ... your logic ...
                                                            return $Router
                                                        },
                                        ),

                );
    }
}
```